# Connecting to Oracle thru Excel 2013

Tags: oracle, excel-2013

While connecting to Oracle thru Excel 2013, i am getting below error. Oracle is installed on Remote Machine. Please advise how to move forward. Do I need to install something on my local machine?

Thanks

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOFP6.png)

> > The provider being used is depracated System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

Comment: Have you tried the page referenced in the error?

Comment: Do you have "Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater" installed? Is this the first time you've tried to link? Have you installed any Oracle products?

Answer (score 1):

you need do what the error says: install Oracle client

link to Oracle client [32bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)

link to Oracle client [64bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

Comment: Just a note, the 32/64 bit has to match to your Excel version